# Problema de configuración de OpenCv en Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Estoy trabajando en un sistema de visión artificial que requiere de una interfaz grafica (GUI) para la interacción con el usuario.

Después de buscar diferentes soluciones, me decidí por programar con Qt, añadiendo las librerías de opencv para el tratamiento de las imágenes.

He seguido algunos tutoriales que he encontrado, pero al final siempre tengo el mismo problema: si escribo código de opencv, el programa se cierra inesperadamente justo después de comenzar.

Estoy trabajando con opencv 2.4.10 y Qt 5.3.2 con el compilador de Visual Studio (MSCV 2010 para 32bit).

De cara a las pruebas he intentando desarrollar y lanzar el proyecto del que os dejo ahora el código.

- opencvButton.pro:

  ```
  QT       += core gui

  greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

  TARGET = opencvButton
  TEMPLATE = app
  INCLUDEPATH += C:\\opencv\\build\\include
  LIBS += -LC:\\opencv\\build\\x86\\vc10\\lib \
       -lopencv_calib3d2410d \
       -lopencv_contrib2410d \
       -lopencv_core2410d \
       -lopencv_features2d2410d \
       -lopencv_flann2410d \
       -lopencv_gpu2410d \
       -lopencv_highgui2410d \
       -lopencv_imgproc2410d \
       -lopencv_legacy2410d \
       -lopencv_ml2410d \
       -lopencv_nonfree2410d \
       -lopencv_objdetect2410d \
       -lopencv_ocl2410d \
       -lopencv_photo2410d \
       -lopencv_stitching2410d \
       -lopencv_superres2410d \
       -lopencv_ts2410d \
       -lopencv_video2410d \
       -lopencv_videostab2410d


  SOURCES += main.cpp\
      mainwindow.cpp

  HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

  FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
  ```
- mainwindow.h:

  ```
  #ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
  #define MAINWINDOW_H

  #include <QMainWindow>
  #include <QPushButton>
  #include <QMessageBox>
  #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
  #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

  namespace Ui {
       class MainWindow;
  }

  class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
  {
      Q_OBJECT
  public:
      explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      private slots:
      void handleButton();
  private:
      QPushButton *m_button;
  };

  #endif // MAINWINDOW_H
  ```
- main.cpp:

  ```
  #include "mainwindow.h"

  #include <QApplication>

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {
      QApplication app(argc, argv);

      MainWindow mainWindow;
      mainWindow.showMaximized();
      return app.exec();
  }
  ```
- Por último, mainwindow.cpp:
       #include "mainwindow.h"

  ```
   #include <QCoreApplication>

   using namespace cv;

   MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
       : QMainWindow(parent)
  {
       // Create the button, make "this" the parent
       m_button = new QPushButton("Display image", this);
       // set size and location of the button
       m_button->setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(100, 100), QSize(200, 50)));

       // Connect button signal to appropriate slot
       connect(m_button, SIGNAL (released()), this, SLOT (handleButton()));
  }

   void MainWindow::handleButton()
  {
      // Define image path
      String imaloc = "C:\\Users\\Virtualmech\\Desktop\\ipRedCable.png";
      // Mat instance declaration image.
      Mat image;
      // Load imaloc image in Mat instance.
      image = imread(imaloc);
      if(image.empty()){
           QMessageBox::about(this, "Error", "Cannot load image");
      }else{
          // Declare name of window
          namedWindow("Display image");
          // Show image
          imshow("Display image", image);
          // Wait for user interaction
          waitKey(0);
          // Close and destroy window
          destroyAllWindows();
      }
  }
  ```

Este programa consiste en un botón que al clicarlo muestra la imagen que se encuentra en la ruta imaloc.

La salida de la aplicación es:

> Starting C:\Users\Virtualmech\Documents\opencvButton\debug\opencvButton.exe...
>
> The program has unexpectedly finished.
>
> C:\Users\Virtualmech\Documents\opencvButton\debug\opencvButton.exe crashed

Y esto sucede tal y como empieza.

Si comento el código de opencv en mainwindow.cpp, el programa funciona perfectamente:

[image: El programa funciona y muestra el QMessageBox]

Ahora bien, con sólo declarar (sin llegar ni a definir) una instancia de **Mat**, la aplicación deja de funcionar y muestra de nuevo la misma salida de antes:

[[image: La aplicación se cierra inesperadamente]]

Creo que se debe a un error de configuración, pero no soy capaz de encontrar dónde.

¿Podría alguna darme una pista?

Gracias por su ayuda y tiempo.

Comment: Debes de traducir tu pregunta o publicarla en (StackOverflow en inglés)[www.stackoverflow.com]

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque la pregunta está en inglés

Comment: @César Hoyos, You have that publish the question on english section, https://stackoverflow.com if you talk on spanish, you can edit the question.

Comment: Sí, perdón, me equivoqué de página a la hora de publicarla. Procedo a la traducción de la duda. Mil disculpas.

Answer (score 1):

Primero, cuando tu applicacion termina de forma inesperada debes  compilar con simbolos de depuracion(Debug, como tienes en tus captura de pantalla) y despues iniciar el depurador.

Se que la pregunta es vieja, pero propongo una solucion para par el futuro.

Si quieres mostrar una imagen de OpenCV (en esencia un objeto tipo `cv::Mat`), lo ideal es que lo conviertas a un tipo de dato propio de Qt por ejemplo `QPixmap` o `QImage`, y despues mostrarlo en un QLabel. A continuacion un ejemplo utilizando tu click de boton:

```
void MainWindow::handleButton()
{
    String imaloc = "C:\\Users\\Virtualmech\\Desktop\\ipRedCable.png";
    Mat image;
    image = imread(imaloc);

    if(!image.data){
        QMessageBox::about(this, "Error", "Cannot load image");
    }else{
        //Convertimos el tipo Mat a QPixmap
        //Obtenemos el buffer de bytes con el miembro "data" 
        auto buffer = (unsigned char*) image.data;

        QImage image_qt(buffer, image.cols, image.rows, QImage::Format_RGB888);
        auto pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image_qt);  

        //Lo mostramos con un QLabel
        ui->label->setPixmap(pixmap);
        //NOTA: debemos definir nuestro label en el archico *.ui con QtDesigner
   }
}
```